# Restart KDE without reboot

Tags: linux, x11, kde-plasma

I am using KDE Plasma Version 5.5.5 on my Laptop and frequently plug in and unplug different external screens. That causes me following problems:

- External monitor stays black after plugging it in.
- I cannot set the internal monitor as primary monitor after unplugging the external.
- The panel at the bottom vanishes.
- Artifacts in windows such as a vanished title bar.

Sometimes the following helps:

```
killall plasmashell
kstart plasmashell
```

or

```
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 1680x1050 --primary
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 1920x1080 --primary
xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1680x1050
xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080
```

or just the plain command without any options:

```
xrandr
```

Is there another way of restarting Plasma and rerendering all windows that is more effective? Without rebooting or logging out?

Answer (score 4):

For different reasons than yours, sometimes I also need to *restart* or *recover* the desktop environment of my computer, which is also based on KDE. To be precise, while I write this answer I'm using these software elements:

- Kubuntu 17.04
- KDE Frameworks 5.31.0
- Qt 5.7.1 (compiled with 5.7.1)
- *xcb* windows system

Given that context, the recovery procedure I apply is based on [a previous answer I found some time ago at the Super User web site](https://superuser.com/a/933894), which I then wrote in a simple Bash script that has this important line:

> kbuildsycoca5 && kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell

I named that script file *restart-kde5-plasmashell* and stored it at the base of my home directory. To execute it, I go to a shell terminal (a *Yakuake* tab in my case) and run it in any of these ways:

1. The way I take most of the times, which needs to keep the terminal open and receives the generated output and/or error messages:

> source ~/restart-kde5-plasmashell

2. The way I seldom use, which would do the job in the background, allowing me to close the terminal after I check that it worked fine:

> source ~/restart-kde5-plasmashell &

Another way to run that script would be by granting execution permissions to the *restart-kde5-plasmashell* file and starting it like this:

> ~/restart-kde5-plasmashell

Finally, I want to highlight a couple of facts:

- KDE works fine most of the time, but when I do things that exhaust the system resources, especially main memory, some system processes could fail, including the desktop environment or one of its subsystems
- The procedure I described normally works, but there have been situations where I needed to completely restart the computer

That's all for now.

Answer (score 2):

Try `kwin --replace &`. It should restart most of the KDE services (if not all).

Answer (score 1):

First try restarting plasmashell as this usually resolves black screen issues. Open KRunner and run `plasmashell --replace` or `killall plasmashell && kstart plasmashell`

If this doesn't work, you can try restarting the display manager.
For X11 `pkill -ABRT kwin_x11` and for Wayland `pkill -ABRT kwin_wayland`.

If none of this worked, just reboot...